# Getting Current/Evaluated Sum of Array of BoolVars While Solving in ORTools in Python

Tags: python, or-tools

I am using ortools with a Maximize objective that calls a function to get back a certain value and maximizes against that value. I would like to pass a variable into that function from the current status of the solver as it's running so that the function can make use of that variable in returning this number.

Without needing this value, I can do something like this:

`model.Maximize(sum([get_value(day, time, employee) for day in all_slots for time in all_slots[day] for employee in employees]))`

I would like to add a fourth variable to get_value where I pass in the sum of an array from the solver. Basically this is the same idea as calling solver.Value() but while the solver is running. Below is not real, but imagine days_worked is an array of boolvars that is, of course, changing as the solver runs.

`model.Maximize(sum([get_value(day, time, employee, sum(days_worked)) for day in all_slots for time in all_slots[day] for employee in employees]))`

Is there a way to do this? Hopefully this explanation makes any sense.

Comment: just wrote sum(variables). No need to get_value()

Comment: You cannot access the value of a variable while it is solving, you have to model it another way